# arithmetic expression: expecting EOF: "008 +1"

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

My script ./make_shift_ln_o_dummy.sh:

```
for i in  `seq -w 0 272`
do
y=0
x=1
echo $i
y=$(($i +$x))
echo $y
done
```

My output with error message:
arithmetic expression: expecting EOF: "008 +1"

```
000
1
001
2
002
3
003
4
004
5
005
6
006
7
007
8
008
./make_shift_ln_o_dummy.sh: 25: arithmetic expression: expecting EOF: "008 +1"
```

Why does it happen? What do I do wrong? How should I change it to the output of 272?

Comment: I think 008 is used as a hex-value. `0x008` is an invalid value for Hex.

Comment: @Gabe I'm not sure that editing answers to fix substantive errors is the best use of edit, therefore I rolled it back.

Comment: Hex is not octal, see the other answers.

Answer (score 5):

008 is an octal number. You can specify you want to use a base-10 number in your arithmetic expression:

```
y=$((10#$i +$x))
```

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic

Answer (score 4):

*Why does it happen?*

The bash expression evaluator sees the leading `0` and assumes that an octal constant is going to follow but `8` is not a valid octal digit.

Version 4.2 of `bash` gives a more helpful diagnostic:

```
$ echo $((007 + 1))
8
$ echo $((008 + 1))
bash: 008: value too great for base (error token is "008")
```

The answer [from anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10515557/282912) above gave the "how to fix" which is why I upvoted it.

Answer (score 2):

No need to use `seq` here. You can use bash arithmetic features like this:

```
for ((i=0; i<272; i++))
do
   y=0
   x=1
   printf "%03d\n" $i
   y=$(($i + $x))
   printf "%03d\n" $y
done
```

Comment: Thanks! But how can I get the leading zeros?

Comment: btw `y=$(($i + $x))` can also be rewritten as `y=$((i + x))`

Comment: @anubhava: It can also be written as `((y = i + x))`

Comment: Yes I agree `let y=i+x` OR `((y = i + x))` will be even more simple.

Comment: Please provide an ideone.con code link to produce this error

Comment: As I wrote earlier please reproduce the problem on ideone or any other platform of your choice